# Log Springboot classes (like DefaultMessageListenerContainer) logs to custom file

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, error-logging

I am facing one problem to log DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java (which is as Springboot class) error logs in a custom file using Log4j2 configuration.

Below is the configuration setup in Log4j2.xml file:

```
<Logger name="org.springframework.jms.listener.DeafultMessageListenerContainer" level="error">
    <AppenderRef ref="customErrorFile">
</Logger>
```

But still I am getting below error logs in Console output and not in custom file.
Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

```
ERROR [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1) Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'wfQueue' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=44, maxAttempts=unlimited}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Below are two different options to print **DeafultMessageListenerContainer** class logs in custom file:

1. Add Exception Listener implementation by using setExceptionListener(), and print custom logs in onJmsException() method, like below:

   ```
    public class MyExceptionListener implements ExceptionListener{

      @Override
      public void onException(JMSException arg0) {
        customErrorLogger.error("Custom error message");
      }
    }
   ```

   And set exception listener as below:

   ```
   deafultMessageListenerContainer.setExceptionListener(new MyExceptionListener());
   ```
2. **DeafultMessageListenerContainer** (Spring class) is using "this.logger" to print exception/error logs so though to add **DeafultMessageListenerContainer**  class package as Logger in Log4j2.xml. But "this.logger" is defined in parent class of this listener class which is **JmsAccessor** class, so defining below Logger in Log4j2.xml also solved this issue:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
      <Appender-ref ref="customErrorFile" level="error"/>
   </Logger>
   ```